# Decompose Measurable Set into Two Measurable subsets

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set (with positive measure).

Under what suitable conditions can we write $E=A\cup B$, where $A$ and $B$ are measurable with positive measure?

What I understand is that this is not always true for arbitrary decompositions, for instance $E=[0,1]$ can be decomposed into the Vitali Set and its complement (which are both non-measurable).

Thanks for any help.

Some other trivial examples I can think of are:

- $E$ is an interval, can be decomposed into two intervals
- $E$ is already known to be the union of two measurable sets with positive measure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $E$ is a Lebesgue-measurable subset of $\mathbb R$ with $\mu(E)\gt0.$ Then the function $f(x)=\mu(E\cap(-\infty,x])$ is continuous, so it assumes all values between $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(+\infty)=\mu(E).$ Choose $x$ with $f(x)=\frac12\mu(E)$ and decompose $E$ into the sets $A=E\cap(-\infty,x]$ and $B=E\cap(x,+\infty).$

**P.S.** The function $f(x)$ is continuous because $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|.$

Comment: Nice. Just to ask why is $f(x)$ continuous? It is not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|$$

Comment: I see it now, thanks

Comment: @2015 $f(+\infty)$ and $f(-\infty)$ are standard notations for $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$ respectively. See, e.g., Definition II on p. 42 of John M. H. Olmsted, *Real Variables*, Appleton-Century-Crofts, New York, 1956.